# Write a function that removes the last char from a String in C. Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying to implement the function as explained in the subject, but I get the error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. What is my mistake?

```
char* removelast(char* s) {
   char* r = s; 
   while (*s) {
       s++;
   }
   s--;
   *s = '\0';
   return r;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This should work for non `const char *`s... Unless you are calling it with hard coded string like: `removelast("Hello World!");`

Comment: @AlexLop. No it doesn't. It fails for empty strings.

Comment: s[strlen(s) - 1] = 0;

Comment: @Swordfish - right, for empty too

Comment: @purec `strlen(s)` might be `0` ...

Comment: No segmentation fault. It works.

Comment: @Swordfish, then if(s[0])...

Comment: @purec No segfault doesn't mean it works. With a string whose first element is `'\0'`, it makes an out of bounds write before the start of the string.

Comment: Insert additional check for zero-length strings.

Comment: Heaven forbid `s` represents a *string-literal* passed to `removelast()`. Show us what you are passing to your function and where it is declared and populated.

Comment: char *x = "hello";  // I pass this

Comment: printf("%s\n",removelast(x));  I call it like this

Comment: @skalion If this is the input you wrote (non mutable string `const char *`) then answer should solve your issue.

Comment: I recommend checking compilation options and enable warnings if not already

Comment: I wonder why 3 up votes for this question, this is very ambiguous and most important information is hidden

Answer (score 1):

The following code has several issues:

```
char* removelast(char* s) {
   char* r = s; 
   while (*s) {
       s++;
   }
   s--;
   *s = '\0';
   return r;
}
```

1. It doesn't check for input validity like `s==NULL`
2. If the input is an empty string (as was remarked by @Swordfish in the comments) this code will invoke *undefined behavior*.
3. If the input is `const char *` (like "Hello World!") this code also invokes *undefined behavior*.

I would suggest to change the function signature to `char *removeLast(const char * s)`, check for input validity, allocate **new** buffer for the string without the last character. Copy the required characters from `s` to the new string and return its pointer.

Something like that (hope it works, didn't check it)

```
char *removeLast(const char *s)
{
    char *newStr = NULL;
    size_t sLen; // length of the 's' string

    // check for 's' validity (not NULL and not empty) and successful 'malloc'
    if ( s && (sLen = strlen(s)) && (newStr = malloc(sLen)) )
    {
        int res = strcpy_s(newStr, sLen - 1, s);
        if (!res)
        {
            newStr[sLen - 1] = '\0';
        }
        else // strcpy_s error
        {
            free(newStr);
            newStr = NULL;
        }
    }

    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: A simple test for `NULL` or *empty-string* is simply `if (!s || !*s) {/* handle error */}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You are right but by `sLen = strlen(s)` I am also saving the length for the further use in (the common) case when the input is valid.

Comment: Yep, no qualms about that, but with the `if (!s || !*s)`, you avoid ever having to call `strlen` if it is empty `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin :) Philosophy of optimization.... I assume that in "error" case the performance is not critical. This way the code looks simple, without too long lines and with fewer `if`s.

Comment: @AlexLop. I totally disagree. Your function violates the SRP. Documentation that says that calling the function with a non-mutable string is UB should be sufficient.

Comment: @Swordfish What documentation are you talking about? `removeLast` is under you implementation and you should decide/define how it behaves

Comment: @AlexLop. About the comment line above the signature that states that the function is not to be called with immutable strings.

Comment: @Swordfish Changing the signature was just a suggestion for cleaner, in my opinion, code with fewer potential bugs in the usage of this function. I never stated that this is the only proper way to implement it.

Comment: Note, I'm not saying any one is "more right" than the other. Readability is far more important that any meaningless micro-optimization at this level. In these cases I generally just check `if (!s || !*s) return;` and just bail at that point. I would be equally happy going to the `strlen` route (given that 99% of the time `s` will not be `NULL` or empty `:)`